# EasyPhp unexpected end of mysql

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I am using EasyPHP 13.1. I run a windows 8 (64 bit) machine. I have been using easyphp for 2 years.

I recently created a new database, named "ukbm001leadprocessing_201411".

Every time I start the EasyPHP application I get the following message: "unexpected end of mysql... See log file ?".

[image]

I have a feeling that the something within the new database I have created is corrupt. I have 3 other databases within this instance which I would like to keep.

```
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-11-11 19:07:48 2254 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 1600647
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: File '2014-11-07 12:09:11 33cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2014-11-07 12:09:11 33cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found. ', errno 13)
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Binlog end
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-11-11 19:07:48 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1600657
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-11-11 19:07:49 6324 [Note] C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql    \bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

In the "mysql-bin.index" file I found this at the bottom.

```
2014-11-07 11:50:08 1914 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2014-11-07 11:50:08 1914 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "ukbm001leadprocessing_201411"."ld_02c_compkey_v01_201411" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
2014-11-07 12:09:11 33cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
```

Any ideas? I have tried:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port        = 3306
```

However this seems to do nothing.

If I can't fix this, I at least want to be able to run MySQL so that I can take a MsqlDump of the other databases.

Here is a link to the my.ini file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0rjqtq8fzqlo7m/my.ini?dl=0

Comment: Can you run MySQL and try to run this query `SELECT count(*) FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats` what does that give you?

Comment: have you recently upgraded to 5.6.11 or has it been like that for a while?

Comment: Every time I start the EasyPHP application I get the following message: "unexpected end of mysql... See log file ?", the instance doesn't start.

Comment: Can't you run mysql without the PHP script? Can you please share you my.ini file? What OS do you use?

Comment: Based on the current conf this is the only machine now but it seems that it was involved in replication. Was it in replication? I would try to run mysql alone in the command line. First change the port to something like 3307 to ensure no one is reading out of this server. Then I would remove force-recovery and try to run MySQL in the client so you can see the error being reported on the screen. You would have to also temporary remove the log-bin from my.ini please check this answer to get the exact error http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81751/how-to-investegate-mysql-crash-on-windows

Comment: I'm sure this is possible, I am using easyphp. I can't run mysql in cmd unless easyphp is turned on and when I turn it on I get this error.

Comment: Have you tried running mysql from the command line? What error do you get when you try this command? mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" --console    Make sure you change the path to my.ini file